# Sails.js Waterline ORM: .findOrCreate() does not have .populate() method

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, models, waterline

I am working with a Model association and everything works fine. However, I just noticed the Model findOrCreate() method does not have a `populate()` method:

`TypeError: Model.findOrCreate(...).populate is not a function`

Is this by design, and if so, what would be the reason? Seems like an important feature to me.

Comment: Can you add the complete code showing how you tried it?

Comment: Taking day off, will update later. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails can't know if the record will be found or created.
In the case the record is created, the method `findOrCreate()` act like `create()` method. Since this method does not have `populate()` method, `findOrCreate()` can't have it either.

Comment: Yes, I think `update()` doesn't allow populate too. I don't know the internals, but since a `findOrCreate()` and `update()` could return the actual existing record, having it return the associations would be a real nice shorthand. It seems a waste to do `findOrCreate()` and then `find().populate()` just to get all records. I guess this is the answer and I will add as a feature request. Thanks!